# Kernel log littered with re-mount attempts because of going to/from battery mode. How do i turn it off?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu, linux-kernel, ext4

My boot times became a bit too much so i decided to take a look ad kernel log to see what might be causing the problem..

There i noticed repeating:

```
12/17/11 02:25:28 PM    EXT4-fs (sda6)  re-mounted. Opts: data=writeback,errors=remount-ro,commit=60,commit=600
12/17/11 02:25:29 PM    EXT4-fs (sda7)  re-mounted. Opts: data=writeback,errors=remount-ro,commit=60,commit=600
12/17/11 02:25:29 PM    EXT4-fs (sda2)  re-mounted. Opts: data=writeback,errors=remount-ro,commit=60,commit=600
```

New messages of this kind continue to appear after the system is up and running, which is strange as i got all the filesystems mounted.

How to stop the remount attempts?

Some info.

My fstab:

```
#sda6
UUID=20fee089-ad39-4264-91f0-39aad7c84809 /               ext4    defaults,data=writeback,errors=remount-ro,commit=60,noatime 0       1
#sda7
UUID=b58528df-37fd-46c8-8160-d7dc0efc78cd /home           ext4    defaults,data=writeback,errors=remount-ro,commit=60,noatime 0       1
#sda2
UUID=ee463441-e841-40ab-b255-f14db4077b61 /media/stuff    ext4    defaults,data=writeback,errors=remount-ro,commit=60,noatime 0       1
```

I'm on kubuntu oneiric, Linux 3.1.4-030104-generic x86_64 kernel.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

ok i found out on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32960/ext34-commit-option-and-filesystem-integrity) that it's because of going to and from battery power. Since my power socket is a bit loose, the switching happens all the time unless i have my laptop put on something stable like a desk.

So my new question is: How do i disable this funcionality? I don't care if the disk has to spin up more often.

Comment: Did you run fsck ?

Comment: @Maxime see my edit.

Comment: Ok, does my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you want to disable is controlled by the following script :

`/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/journal-commit`

As said on the [Ubuntu help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower#Using_less_power_with_pm-powersave) :

> to disable a script from /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/ simply create an empty file in /etc/pm/power.d/ with the same name and without the execute bit set.

So, let's just do that :

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/journal-commit
```

Comment: i must've missed that when i read that page and i thought it can be only customized, but not turned off. stupid me. thanks.